# Searching multiple columns of Datatable within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am currently trying to make an R shiny app where the user can search across multiple columns in each row. This function works using the `datatable` function from the `DT` package outside of the shiny environment. Using the `iris` dataset as an example, I want to search for all rows containing the values; 5.1, 3.5, and 1.4. If I type the following string in the search box of the interactive datatable window "5.1 3.5 1.4" rows 1 and 18 are displayed.

```
library(DT)
head(iris)

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa


datatable(iris)
```

The problem is when I try and do the same thing within a shiny environment I receive the message

> No matching records found.

For example:

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')))),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
        iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
      )
    }
  )
}
```

Does anyone have a work around, or could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you set `server = FALSE` inside of `renderDataTable`, it works. Apparently Shiny has a problem with the spaces, for some reason; probably a bug.

Comment: Hey alistaire, yep I just found that. Thanks.

Comment: @alistaire `server = TRUE` is tricky. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

To anyone else with the same issue you need to `server=FALSE` to the `renderDataTable` function.

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')))),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
        iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE), server = FALSE
      )
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: What if one is required to use Server side Processing and use `server=TRUE`?

Comment: @keshr3106 The solution is not very straightforward. I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: I have implemented the [smart filtering](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.smart) in the server-side processing mode and it is enabled by default. With **DT** >= 0.2.29, it should work out of the box:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, options = list(search = list(search = '5.1 3.5 1.4'))
    )
  }
)
```

[image: smart filtering in DT in the server mode]

---

**You can ignore the old answer below.**

You can enable regular expressions in searching ([see more examples in the **DT** documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/007-search.html)).

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, options = list(search = list(regex = TRUE))
    )
  }
)
```

In the above example, I used the regular expression `5.1|3.5|1.4`. Please note that it means "find the values 5.1, 3.5, *or* 1.4 in *any* columns". If you need to find 5.1 in the first column, 3.5 in the second column, and 1.4 in third column, there is no way to do it in the mode of server-side processing with a single search string (a single regular expression cannot express this). You have to use either the client-side processing (i.e., `server = FALSE`, as you have discovered), or sort the columns to find the combination you need:

[image: regex in DT]

or use column filters to filter individual columns:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')))),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, filter = 'top'
    )
  }
)
```

[image: column filters in DT]

Comment: Hi Yihui Xie...! This is great. Can we generate the count of rows filtered?